# How to combine JQuery and RequireJS in an object-oriented, well-structured manner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, requirejs

I'm developing a visual HTML editing tool. I'm writing the frontend on top of the **Yeoman** *webapp* template, and using **JQuery** for DOM manipulation and **RequireJS** to structure my code.

Example code (contents of **/app/scripts/views/drawing/draw-element.js** so you can get a feeling for my directory structure):

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'domReady'], function ($, $UI) {
    'use strict';

    function DrawElement (elementId) {
        this.jqElement = $("#" + elementId);
        console.log('DrawElement: ', this, this.jqElement); // This is printed when instance is created and looks fine
        this.jqElement.addClass("draw_element"); // Has no effect. Why is this not working?

        this.jqElement.click(function (eventObject) {
            this.jqElement.addClass("selected");
        })

        return this;
    }

    return DrawElement;

});
```

I later use DrawElement like this:

```
var drawElement = new DrawElement("box1");
```

**Question:** what is the recommended way of using JQuery in a RequireJS-based app? You can see how I use JQuery-statements above.

Comment: For jQuery to find an element by id, it has to be `$("#id")`. So, does the `elementId` argument include the `#`?

Comment: You found it, thanks!